# develop eclipse plugin for existing desktop application

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, plugins

I want to develop eclipse plugin on top of an existing desktop application. The desktop application has already been developed in Java Swing and I want to create eclipse plugin which will use this existing desktop application as well as also use existing eclipse features like refactoring etc.

So far, I have found following resources,

- Book

  - Eclipse Plug-ins by Eric Clayberg
  - Eclipse 4 Plug-in Development by Example Beginner's Guide
- Other resources include

  - Eclipse, RCP, Plugin and OSGi Development by vogella
  - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-plugindev1/index.html
  - http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/02/09/eclipse.html

I want to start developing eclipse plugin but not sure how to start. I start to read vogella tutorial but it is talking about eclipse RCP which I am not sure is what i need or not? If anyone can provide me direction and give me starting point, i will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Eclipse plug-in always runs as part of an Eclipse RCP. Eclipse itself is a (very large) RCP so you can develop the plug-in to run as part of Eclipse, or you can write your own RCP from scratch.

Comment: so, you mean i need to develop another RCP with in eclipse? and what is best resource to study about RCP then?

Comment: I do not understand your point? Can you please clarify should I develop RCP or plugin? Sorry, if I understand incorrectly

Comment: Everything in Eclipse is a plugin. You can add your plugins to an existing Eclipse installation or you can package your plugins plus some from Eclipse in to your own RCP - that is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for you answer greg. I appreciate. Can you please confirm me my understanding now?  Since I will need to develop plugin that will require to use existing dekstop application plus other eclipse features, so I will develop my own RCP? Is that right?